# Previous and Next - exclude the amount of pages shown

Tags: php, wordpress, function

My current function shows the amount of pages and the buttons next and previous. My aim is to only show the Previous and Next buttons but having trouble editing this function.

Here is the function code

```
function mts_wp_link_pages_args( $args ) {
    global $page, $numpages, $more, $pagenow;
    if ( !$args['next_or_number'] == 'next_and_number' )
        return $args; 
    $args['next_or_number'] = 'number'; 
    if ( !$more )
        return $args; 
    if( $page-1 ) 
        $args['before'] .= _wp_link_page( $page-1 )
        . $args['link_before']. $args['previouspagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
    ;
    if ( $page<$numpages ) 

        $args['after'] = _wp_link_page( $page+1 )
        . $args['link_before'] . $args['nextpagelink'] . $args['link_after'] . '</a>'
        . $args['after']
    ;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_link_pages_args', 'mts_wp_link_pages_args' );
```

and this is what is being called in the single.php

```
 <?php wp_link_pages(array('before' => '<div class="pagination">', 'after' => '</div>', 'link_before'  => '<span class="current"><span class="currenttext">', 'link_after' => '</span></span>', 'next_or_number' => 'next_and_number', 'nextpagelink' => __('Next','mythemeshop'), 'previouspagelink' => __('Previous','mythemeshop'), 'pagelink' => '%','echo' => 1 )); ?>
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out

```
<?php 

global $page, $pages;


wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div style="text-align: center;" class="page-link-next-prev">', 
'after' => '', 'previouspagelink' => '<span style="float:left;min-width: 60px;
background-color: #d86043;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 5px 20px;
color: #FFF;" class="meta-item">Previous post</span>', 'nextpagelink' => '', 
'next_or_number' => 'next' ) ); 



echo('<span style="text-align: center;">'.$page.' of '.count($pages).'</span>');




wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '', 
'after' => '</div>', 
'previouspagelink' => '', 
'nextpagelink' => '<span style="float:right; min-width: 60px;
background-color: #d86043;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 5px 20px;
color: #FFF;" class="meta-item">Next post</span>', 'next_or_number' => 'next' ) ); 

?>
```